# Byte slice partial copy

Tags: go

I'm rather new with go and I'm trying to access a portion of a byte slice and copy to a another fixed length byte slice but doesn't find the proper solution.

My best bet was :

```
var extracted []byte
var newSlice [512]byte = extracted[0 : 511]
```

But this gives me a conversion error :

`cannot use extracted[0:511] (value of type []byte) as [512]byte value in variable declarationcompilerIncompatibleAssign`

Notes :

- this will be in a loop to iterate over the entire size of extracted 512 bytes at a time;
- extracted actually has a fixed size of 512*n bytes, but if I fix that length I have the same issue

I thought I could use a io.Reader but this approach failed miserably as well.

Any help welcome :)

Comment: "a another fixed length byte slice" there is no such thing. A _slice_ by definition is of variabel size. The things with fixed size are called arrays and behave totally different. Why not use a slice: `var cp = make([]byte, 512); copy(cp, extracted[0 : 512]` ? (Note 1: you got the upper bound wrong.) (Note 2: Arrays are used seldomly in Go.)

Comment: indeed, note that in my original question `copy` was supposed to be a var not a "copy" function (bad attempt at making my question more abstract / general).

The solution seems indeed to use copy but as : 
```
var newSlice [512]byte 
copy(pixels[:], extracted[0:512])
```

I need the output to be of type [512]byte it will be fed to a chan which expect this type.

Comment: @EdwinJoassart, in comments, use single backticks to mark code blocks up ;-) Triple backticks are for multiline blocks only, which is not applicable to comments anyway.

Comment: @kostix i figure right after posting, but realized that i cannot edit comments :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches:

- [Convert the slice to an array pointer](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions_from_slice_to_array_pointer) and dereference that pointer:

  ```
  var pixels [512]byte
  pixels = *(*[512]byte)(extracted[:512])
  ```

  This can be done in one statement using a [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

  ```
  pixels := *(*[512]byte)(extracted[:512])
  ```
- Use the builtin [copy](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#copy) function to copy elements from a slice to an array (this point was covered in the question comments):

  ```
  var pixels [512]byte
  copy(pixels[:], extracted[:512])
  ```